# is this possible to change "Y" possition of barbutton?

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

[image]
Here is my code of `UIBarButtonItem` , i have added imageInsets for adding "Y" position to it , but it is not working.

```
let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
leftBarButtonItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0)
leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = .red
navigationItem.setRightBarButton(leftBarButtonItem, animated: true)
```

Comment: Provide `top:` how many pixel you want to put it down in `UIEdgeInsets`.

Comment: Or you can create `UIButton` then create `UIView` and add button into that. After that create `let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: <UIView>)`.

Comment: VRAwesome can you provide code for it?

Answer (score 1):

It is too simple thing. You can try below ways :

Directly using `UIBarButtonItem` :

```
let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon_2"), style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(rightBtnClicked(_:)))
leftBarButtonItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0)
leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = .red
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(leftBarButtonItem, animated: true)
```

OR By custom button :

```
let rightButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
rightButton.backgroundColor = .clear
rightButton.tintColor = .red
rightButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10), size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
//rightButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
//rightButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0)
//rightButton.contentVerticalAlignment = .bottom
rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_1"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightBtnClicked(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

let btnView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)))
btnView.backgroundColor = .clear
btnView.addSubview(rightButton)

let barBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnView)
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(barBtn, animated: true)
```

Comment: thanks it working but we cant move that button  more then navigation bar height more 25 that button back to my title of navigation bar

Comment: Yeah, then adjust coordinates as per your requirements.

Comment: please check screeshot i added that rightbarbutton goes back to navigation title , i set top : 20 , letft : 20, bottom:15,right:0

Comment: Why you are setting top:20, please make 10. And make bottom:0

Comment: i want right bar button exactly infront of navigation title

Comment: How can anyone set `right bar button` exactly in front of `navigation title` ?